# Appending JSON data from one file to another in Python

Tags: python, json

Consider this code, which is understandably failing:

```
def testDataTransform():
    source = 'data/threads/testFile2.json' 
    newFile = 'data/threads/testFile1.json'

    jX = returnJson(source)
    jY = returnJson(newFile)

    for dataL1 in jX:
        #print dataL1['city']
        for dataL2 in jY:
            if dataL1['city'] == dataL2['city']:
                dataL2.append(dataL1['population']) 

    print dataL2


# end testDataTransform

def returnJson(source):
    #Grab destination file json
    try:
       with open(source) as jsonFile: # Open and verify file is there
        # load JSON object into memory
        j = json.load(jsonFile)

        return j
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        raise
# end returnJson

testDataTransform()
```

The error generated is: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`,
which I now understand is due to trying to use append on a file steam and thus appending my JSON incorrectly. The question is how would I do this correctly? I want to add population data, which is in the `source` file.

JSON structure in testFiles look like this:

```
[

    {
        "city": "New York",
        "lat": 20.1234,
        "long": 32.09876
    },
    {
        "city": "London",
        "lat": 21.1234,
        "long": 37.09876
    },
    {
        "city": "New Jersey",
        "lat": 10.1234,
        "long": 30.09876
    }

]
```

One has a "population" node and other does not. I want to copy that population data from one file to another. How is that done? I wonder if converting the file stream into an array would help, but how do I even do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. It's in this line

```
dataL2.append(dataL1['population'])
```

dataL2 is a dict(), and dict() does not have a method called append

What you want is

```
dataL2["population"] = dataL1['population']
```

Basically, the call to `json.load()` for this file returns a list of dicts(). JSON arrays map to Python lists, JSON objects map to Python dictionaries. To add a new key to a dict, simply set a value on it.

Comment: Well look at that! Nice. But now the values are all the same for every object

Comment: Didn't say that was your only problem :) What's the contents of the other test file?

Comment: check the indentation in your modified code. Is the assignment only happening when the if condition is met?